# Meteor : to get and show github username and email

Tags: javascript, html, github, meteor, meteorite

I've got the username and email address from GitHub API. But it does not show in Meteor. It works perfect with profile.name but not with services.github.username or email

```
 Template.input_box.events = {
"keydown input#message" : function(event){
    if (event.which == 13) { 
    // 13 is the enter key event

        if (Meteor.user())
        {
            var name = Meteor.user().profile.name;
            // var git_userid = Meteor.user().services.github.username;             
            // var git_email = Meteor.user().services.github.email;
        }
```

It's weird, because Meteor.user().services.github.username; works in console mode but if I put in my code and run in local host, it does not show anything... The code that is calling this

```
    {{git_email}} {{git_userid}}  // does not work
    {{name}}    // works
```

How do I make them work so that I can insert the email and username information in my HTML.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the meteor [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_users)

> By default, the current user's username, emails and profile are
>   published to the client.

So you will need to manually publish the user's "services" field on the server.

```
Meteor.publish("userData", function () {
  return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId},
                           {fields: {'services': 1}});
});
```